# How to make an relation between the same columns in different tables?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using symfony 6 with doctrine and i want to map a relation between my tables.

After user register - app generate him an useruuid - which will be using across many tables. Is it possible to make a joincolumn on primary user entity and add to it other tables? Just to make a querybuilder simple.

For example:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    // join column SomeTable
    // join column SomeTable2
        private ?string $uuid = null;
}
```

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SomeTableRepository::class)]
class SomeTable
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    // Join column user
        private ?string $uuid = null;
}
```

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SomeTable2Repository::class)]
class SomeTable2
{
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    // Join column user
        private ?string $uuid = null;
}
```

(I know i can make an uuid field type - its only for testing purposes)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In ORM (object-relational mapping), you will think in terms of Entities and not Tables. Take a look at Doctrine Association Mapping to see all possibilities of entity relationships https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/association-mapping.html